# Angular pipe with several arguments

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-pipe

I'm using this custom made pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Pipe({
  name: 'yesno'
})
export class YesNoPipe implements PipeTransform {
    constructor() {}

    transform(observable: Observable<Array<any>>, args: Array<any>): Observable<Array<any>> {
        console.log(args);
        return observable...
    }
}
```

Into my template, I'm using:

```
<div>
    {{cols | yesno:'yesno':true | async | json}}
</div>
```

However, I'm only receiving only first argument `"yesno"`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a [rest parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#rest-parameters) for your arguments in `transform`

```js
// notice the three dots at: ...args
transform(observable: Observable<any[]>, ...args: any[]): Observable<any[]> {
  console.log(args);
  return observable...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can pass multiple argument with ":" see below example

```
{{ cols | yesno:'yesno':true | async | json }}
```

Also please check pipe code below :

```
export class YesNoPipe implements PipeTransform {    
        transform(value:any, args:any[]):any {
                var arg1 = args[0];
                var arg2 = args[1];
                ...
        }
```